# mysql use EXPLAIN and SELECT rows column alone

Tags: mysql, count, rows, explain

I am willing to get information about the progress of a BIG insert of 10M rows into `out_table` during the `INSERT` execution.

I found that:
query1: `EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM out_table;` gives:

+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+-----------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key                   | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+-----------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+

|  1 | SIMPLE      | out_table| index | NULL          | periodo_cuit_cuil_idx | 22      | NULL | 2518148 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+-----------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+

As I want to show the advance of the `INSERT` script I will run an script that keeps showing the progress. The problem I have is that I cannot get the 'rows'
column alone from the former query.
I've tried to make a `SELECT rows FROM` (query1) and to asign the output to a variable with no luck. Any idea?

Comment: Did you mean insert or are you LOAding from csv or IMPORTINGing from .SQL

Comment: I am inserting from one table into another. The origin table is a myIsam one, the destination table is InnoDB. The count(*) in InnodB is too costly, so I use EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) as a proxy for the number of rows already inserted.
The problem is to select the column rows alone, and not the whole register that outputs EXPLAIN SELECT.

Comment: How about select table_name, table_rows from  information_schema.tables where table_name = ?

Comment: Thank you P.Salmon! That solution is fine for me. The number of rows is coincident with the number of rows obtainded using EXPLICIT. In both cases are an approximation, but is enough for the sake of watching the progress of the insert query.